# How to pass to the status of other views to a custom view in Android?

Tags: android, android-custom-view, custom-view

In my main activity page, I have a custom view as well as some other views such as a radio group. I want to change the behavior of my custom view methods based on the status of these other views in the main activity page. For instance, if the radio group in the main activity page is set to "option 1", I want to draw one shape inside `onTouchEvent` of the custom view and if the radio group is set to "option 2", I want to draw another shape.

When I call `findViewId` inside the `onTouchEvent`, I get null. I thought to define my radio group inside the custom view but I hope there is a more elegant solution and I don't have to do this. I thought to use a singleton but I hope there is an easier solution.

** EDIT:
I found the most intuitive solution for me to be as follows:

In the activity class and inside `onCreate` method, I created a listener inside which I would call a setter method of my custom view to pass the selected option from the radio group. More concretely, in the activity class and inside the `onCreate` method, I had these lines:

```
RadioGroup actionRadioGroup = (RadioGroup) findViewById(R.id.action);
actionRadioGroup.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new 
             RadioGroup.OnCheckedChangeListener() 
{
    @Override
    public void onCheckedChanged(RadioGroup radioGroup, int i) {
       int currAction = radioGroup.getCheckedRadioButtonId();
       MyView myView = (MyView) findViewById(R.id.myview);
       myView.setAction(currAction);
    }
});
```

And in my custom view, I had this method:

```
public void setAction(int currAction) {
     this.currAction = currAction;
     /// other stuff
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest creating interface providing the info you want, implementing it inside your Activity and injecting to the view, like so:

RadioGroupInfoProvider.java

```
public interface RadioGroupInfoProvider {

    String getRadioGroupInfo();
}
```

MainActivity.java

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity implements RadioGroupInfoProvider { 

    //...

    void setUp() {
        YourCustomView yourCustomView = findViewById(R.id.customView);
        yourCustomView.setRadioGroupInfoProvider(this);

    }

    @Override
    String getRadioGroupInfo() {
        return radioGroup.toString()
    }
}
```

CustomView.java

```
void setRadioGroupInfoProvider(RadioGroupInfoProvider radioGroupInfoProvider) {
    this.radioGroupInfoProvider = radioGroupInfoProvider;
}
```

and then inside onTouchEvent:

```
String info = radioGroupInfoProvider.getRadioGroupInfo();
```

Comment: What happens if there are more items that need to communicate with the custom view (text edits) and they depend on the user actions?  For instance how about if an update button is pressed in the main activity and as soon as this happens I want to read some text edits in the main activity and based on that change something in the custom view? Also can I use the interface to pass information from the custom view to the main activity?

Comment: You can create some interface for custom view - you don't need an interface, you can just put some methods in Custom View and call them using the same way as setRadioGroupProvider(...)